# dotfiles not showing up on pi samba mapped from windows

Tags: raspberry-pi, samba

I'm wondering what you need to do to be able to see dotfiles on a samba network drive mapped to a pi.  If I do a `touch test123` on my pi, I can see this file on my windows 10 machine, but if I do a `touch .test123`, this file does not appear:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/devel/thermostat $ touch test123
pi@raspberrypi:~/devel/thermostat $ touch .test123
```

```
p:\devel\thermostat>dir test123
 Volume in drive P is pi
 Volume Serial Number is DB2B-A983

 Directory of p:\devel\thermostat

2022-04-16  03:42 PM                 0 test123
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  10,872,836,096 bytes free

p:\devel\thermostat>dir .test123
 Volume in drive P is pi
 Volume Serial Number is DB2B-A983

 Directory of p:\devel\thermostat

File Not Found
```

My smb.conf file contains the following:

```
[pihome]
  comment = Pi Home
  path=/home/pi
  browseable=Yes
  writeable=Yes
  only guest=no
  create mask=0777
  directory mask=0777
  read only=no
  public=no
```

Is there any way to make the dot files visible to my windows 10 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba automatically sets the Windows 'Hidden' attribute on dotfiles, and your results are normal for hidden files on Windows. They *are* being sent as part of the file list, so you can still see them using `dir /a` in Cmd, or `dir -Force` in PowerShell, and there's nothing special needed to open them directly (e.g. you can just run `notepad .bashrc` if you want).

You can disable this Samba feature using the `hide dot files =` option.